# How to add more actions in the Health cloud Patient List view

Tags: lightning, health-cloud

[image]

In the Picture near the 3, we have Action and Create Task in the dropdown. How can I add more Actions in the drop down like "Create Note", "Log Call"

Answer (score 0):

In general objects we do following to add action to "list view" go to objectManager->object->searchlayout->edit the list view and add whatever action you want or you can create your own quick action and then add if you dont see list view in search layout then you can select "Search layout for classic" and then edit list view

Comment: But the list view seems to be of patient object which indeed is not a standard object instead it is from a managed package i could not find in the object manager can you  help?

Comment: so you saying you can't find "patient" Object in object manager? you can probably try opening a record and clicking on "edit object" there

Comment: Only Edit Page is there no Edit Object available and this is health cloud do you think it is possible?

Comment: may be then they have a different approach generally we use to do this way

Comment: @heeat you can try it on account object i guess patient is a person account

Comment: i did it but no luck